# C# autocomplete not working for Script# in visual studio

Tags: c#, script#

I'm using the fantastic project Script# (http://projects.nikhilk.net/ScriptSharp)
I can't seem to get the autocomplete feature in VisualStudio 2008 working
the .scriptlet files appear as plain text with no code formatting at all

the version of Script# I am using is 0.5.6

I am opening the samples project and looking at HelloWorld.scriptlet

Cheers
Sam

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, currently .scriptlet files don't have a custom editor, and as such are treated as regular text files.

In the next version of script#, the Scriptlet server control is going to work slightly differently. Two changes:

1. Its not going to support inline code. All code must be in a .scriptlet file if you want script code-behind.
2. The scriptlet server control will look for a .scriptlet file instead, and open it up when you choose to Edit Code from the script in design-view. At that point you'll get intellisense.

Of course over the long-term I actually want an editor experience for these. That is the desired implementation...